# Manipulating the css itself, for performance

Tags: html, css

My idea is to use JavaScript to change the HTML content of `<style>` tag, in order to manipulate elements.

Assuming a table with 20,000 cells, i want to hide those who has the `hide` and `hide-me-too` class, instead of getting all the elements - i'll add/remove the HTML content

```
 .hide-me-too, .hide{display:table-cell/none;}
```

of a `style` element in the page.

what i ask is: should i expect problems with different brwosers? performance? any-other-issue?

Comment: Maybe this article will answer your question https://teamtreehouse.com/community/which-is-more-performant-hide-in-jquery-or-display-none-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will try to manipulate the CSSOM to control 20,000 cells you have a problem.

Better if you manipulate the DOM and change classnames.

The any-other-issue, and the most important, is if you have a table structure (`<table><tr><td>`) and you show cells with `display:block` you will crash all your layout. The correct display value for cells is `display: table-cell`. So don't make a single `show()` or `hide()` with jQuery, change the classnames so look like this:

```
.showme {
  display: table-cell;
}

.hide,
.hide-me-too {
  display: none;
}
```

And it's another any-other-issue, that you hide some cells, the columns will not match, so you need to play with `colspan`. Will be hard. Good luck.

Comment: 1. thanks  2. fixed (known, made a mistake coding the example on autopilot)

Comment: upvote: sure.
accepted: not yet.. will wait for some more input.